# How to show that a surface is minimal

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I am reading Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces from M.P. Do Carmo.
In the chapter about minimal surfaces he says that,

(1) A regular parametrized surface is called minimal if its mean curvature vanishes everywhere.

(2)A regular surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is minimal if each of its parametrizations is minimal

So I wanted to show that the catenoid given by
$$x(u,v)=(\cosh(u)\cosh(v),\cosh(u)\sin(v),u)$$
is minimal.

Do I just need to show that the mean curvature $H(p)$ is zero everywhere? Which I would assume according to (1). But why does then (2) state that this needs to be done for every parametrization?

Comment: The clue is that for the mean curvature $H$, to be $0$ is independant of a parametrization. Hence, (1) and (2) are equivalent.

Comment: @Didier so I just need to show that H is 0?

Comment: Yes, this is what you have to do